# PHP Nested Loop - Comparing each item in two arrays and outputting them as checked or unchecked textboxes

Tags: php

I think the title explains most of it. The items of the two arrays that I know are matching strings do not come out as checked checkboxes. What I have:

*Edit: realized I was using the wrong array. However, now I'm only getting the first entry right because of th breaks.

```
<?php
        foreach ($list as $x){
            foreach ($arr as $y){
                if ($x == $y){
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                    echo '</li>';
                        break;
                }
                else {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$x.'" />'.$x.'<br/>';
                    echo '</li>';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Is it just me or do you need to use continue instead of break?

Comment: Somewhat off the point... but this code suggests that only one of the checkboxes will be checked. So I am just curious that why don't you use radiobuttons instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried the script without the `break;` part?
It is quite weird that you use the breaks there.
Moreover, do you also open `<ul>` somewhere?

It is not very clear what you want, please be more specific.